# How to set onclick event on "Rate" in the alert view?(Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is the code snippet: I am a bit confused in how to set `onclick` in alert box in unity?

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        showAlertDialog(new string[] { "Rate Us", "Take 2 min to rate our app", "Rate", "Maybe Later" }, (int obj) => { **refer here**

            Debug.Log("Local Handler called: " + obj);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: showAlertDialog - can you show us what code is here?

Comment: u want me to show my android code or the unity script one?

Comment: Whatever is relevant. I'm assuming you're using an event callback in Unity as well?

Comment: class AlertViewCallback : AndroidJavaProxy
 {
  private System.Action<int> alertHandler;

  public AlertViewCallback(System.Action<int>alertHandlerIn) : base (pluginName + "$AlertViewCallback")
  {
   alertHandler = alertHandlerIn;
  }
  public void onButtonTapped(int index)
  {
   Debug.Log("Button tapped: " + index);
   if (alertHandler != null)
    alertHandler(index);
  }
 }

 static AndroidJavaClass _pluginClass;
 static AndroidJavaObject _pluginInstance

Comment: public static AndroidJavaClass PluginClass
 {
  get {
   if (_pluginClass==null)
   {
    _pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass(pluginName);
    AndroidJavaClass playerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject activity = playerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    _pluginClass.SetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("mainActivity",activity);
   }
   return _pluginClass;
  }
 }

Comment: public static AndroidJavaObject PluginInstance
 {
  get {
   if (_pluginInstance==null)
   {
    _pluginInstance = PluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstance");
   }
   return _pluginInstance;
  }
 }

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

  Debug.Log("Elapsed Time: " + getElapsedTime());

Comment: float elapsedTime = 0;
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
  elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
  if (elapsedTime>=5)
  {
   elapsedTime -= 5;
   Debug.Log("Tick: " + getElapsedTime());
  }

  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
  {
   showAlertDialog(new string[]{"Alert Title","Alert Message","Button 1","Button 2"},(int obj) => {
    Debug.Log("Local Handler called: " + obj);
   });  }
}
 double getElapsedTime()
 {
  if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
   return PluginInstance.Call<double>("getElapsedTime");
  Debug.LogWarning("Wrong platform");

Comment: i just want to know that in the alert view i have to open play store on rate it click and i have stored that as an string in the string array

Comment: Crikey that's a lot of code to be in a comment! Why don't you edit your question and put the code there instead?

Comment: As soon as i paste my code there it displays an error msg to format and lot of code error

Comment: The error is being displayed because i have skipped some lines of code in the comment section.